# jquery Tablesorter - sort field by <input value="value">

Tags: jquery

I want to sort my 4th and 5th field by the information on my INPUT attr VALUE

This is my html:

```
<table class=tablesorter width="764" border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 id="objective3">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Strategy</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Objective</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Status</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Target Date</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Target</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Actual</th>
      <th bgcolor="#396FAE" class="divtopheader1">Cumulative</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="tvertheadersm">Conservation</td>
      <td width="27%" class="tvertheadersm">statutory authority.</td>
      <td width="8%" align="center" valign="middle" class="tbody2">
          <input type=hidden value="1">
           <thewordIMGshouldgohere src="images/1" alt="Objective met" width=30 height=40 />
      </td>
      <td width="11%" align=center class="tbody2">
          <input type=hidden value="092010">September<br>2010</td>
          <td align=center class="tbody2">14 agencies</td>
      <td align=center class="tbody2">14 agencies</td>
      <td align=center class="tbody2">0 agencies</td>
    </tr>
```

This is my jquery, here I am trying only for the 5th field but is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'input',
        is: function(s) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            // format your data for normalization
            return $("td input",$(s)).attr("value");
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });

    $("table").tablesorter({
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object
        headers: {
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero)
            5: {
                sorter:'input'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is welcome!!!

Happy Holidays  :-)

Néstor

Answer (score 7):

"s" passed to format() function is a string with cell content. You should rewrite your function to look like this

```
format: function(s) {
    // format your data for normalization
    return $($.trim(s)).val();
}
```

Update: took a closer look at your code and at a tablesorter.addParser

It looks like format() is called with 3 parameters, 3rd one being the cell it's applied on. Considering this, code can be rewritten like this:

```
format: function(s, table, cell) {
  return $('input', cell).val();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RyCWM/1/

Comment: @GermanRumm - in my case a table column - a cell is having either input or TextNode. Some are 'input' & some are Simple TextNodes. In that case Input Value is my priority but if 'input' doesnot exist for that cell then should go for 'Text'. Can you suggest anything on this?

Comment: @nirav try `return $('input', cell).val() || $(cell).text()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the contents of the current input, you should call on the onchange events the INPUT $("table").trigger("update"); 
A parser must then looks like that:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.tablesorter.addParser({
            // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method$.tablesorter.addParser({
            // set a unique id
            id:'input',
            is:function (s) {
                // return false so this parser is not auto detected
                return false;
            },
            format:function (s) {
                // format your data for normalization
                var obj=$($.trim(s));
                var id=obj[0].id;
                var text=$("#"+id)[0].value;
                return text;
            },
            // set type, either numeric or text
            type:'text'
        });

        $("table").tablesorter({
            // pass the headers argument and assing a object
            headers:{
                3:{
                    sorter:'input'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```